# What is the purpose of NSAttributed String?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch

As in the header, I am having trouble understanding the purpose of attributed strings other than the fact that it is used in cases like the UI for instance UIRefreshControl inside the UITableViewController.

What benefits does it give? Does it just allow for certain strings to have custom colors, fonts and such?

Comment: you can read all about it here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAttributedString_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000166-95039

Comment: Thanks Eugene, I always forget that the dev docs online is more informative than the one within XCode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NSAttributedString** is quite useful in many cases.

In can render a custom font, custom color for you labels; it can apply many different text styles like underline, strikethrough, bold, italic, header; or to hightlight any part of a string you want.

But the best part is, in my opinion, that you can even render HTML text inside a label instance just by using **NSAttributedString**, in case you want to display styled text with CSS:

```
NSString *htmlString = @"<style>h1{ color: cyan }</style>"
                       "<h1>Hello World</h1> "
                       "<p>This is a paragraph</p>";

NSDictionary *option = @{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType };
NSError *dealDescriptionAttributedError;
NSData *dealDescriptionData = [string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF16StringEncoding];
NSAttributedString *htmlAttributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:dealDescriptionData
                                                                            options:option
                                                                 documentAttributes:nil
                                                                              error:&dealDescriptionAttributedError];
```

Answer (score 1):

You are right, and that's all it does. It allows you to assign visual attributes to any part of the string.

Indeed it is quite useful in some cases. For example, you can put strikethrough attribute on some text, to visually indicate that the text was deleted.

Another example, say you have a short paragraph displayed as a label in black color, with attributed string, you can highlight couple keywords in red.

Comment: On competing platforms, doing things like "a button with styled text inside" can be extremely difficult to implement. Don't underestimate the value-add here.